# Python Multiprocessing Pool With Infinite While Loop

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, pool

I am attempting to run an infinite while loop that will call a function that makes an API call. Each API call can take between 9-12 seconds and I want x processes constantly running.

I've attempted some of the existing pool examples but they seem to take a function along with a list of arguments. My function generates all inputs needed.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
from random import randint
from time import sleep

def loop_a():
    while 1:
        wait = randint(5,9)
        print("now waiting" + str(wait) + " seconds")
        sleep(wait)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Initialize two separate while loops that can call/wait for responses independently  
    Process(target=loop_a).start()
    Process(target=loop_a).start()
```

This sample code I found from another question solves my problem mostly, but I am wondering if there is an elegant way to define how many processes to run at once. Id like to be able to enter the number of processes as a parameter rather than defining a new line for each process. Is there a nice way to accomplish this?

This snippet seems to fix the issue I was facing.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    [Process(target=loop_a).start() for x in range(2)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Pool`

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(processes=2) # define number of processes
results = [pool.apply(loop_a) for x in range(2)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I'm still having trouble getting your answer to generate the output I am looking for. Whenever I modify my code to sleep a certain time period and report on the sleep time, your code only seems to print one thread.

Using the for syntax you provided I have accomplished exactly what I need. Thank you for your assistance.